# GraphQL Front-end React

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I created the variable to receive the GraphQL requisition

```
const users = gql`
  getCompanyById(id: "Jwx7C2RAekf1XZmUf9kX") {
    __typename
    ... on Company {
      name
      usersConnection(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            firstName
            lastName
            phone
            email
            cpf
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

But at front-end throw this error.

```
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "getCompanyById".
```

Comment: What GraphQL client are you using for React? It looks like you're missing the term query before your getCompanyById as well (again depending on the client)\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing the curly brackets before getCompanyById. Try this:

```
const users = gql` {
  getCompanyById(query: {id: "Jwx7C2RAekf1XZmUf9kX"}) {
    __typename
    ... on Company {
      name
      usersConnection(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            firstName
            lastName
            phone
            email
            cpf
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

}
`;